# Asymptotic analysis of an integral - continuous time random walk framework

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals, mathematical-physics

In the problem of continuous time random walk, I have a summation of the form
$$
P(x,t)=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp\left[-x^2/(2N\sigma^2)\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi N \sigma^2}} \left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^N \frac{e^{-t/\tau}}{N!}
$$

While this summation can't be directly evaluated, is it possible to evaluate the integral where I consider N to vary continuously

$$
P(x,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\;dN\; \frac{\exp\left[-x^2/(2N\sigma^2)\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi N \sigma^2}} \left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^N \frac{e^{-t/\tau}}{\Gamma(N+1)}
$$

As a matter of fact, for large values of $x$ and $t$, the integral can be estimated to be,
$$
P(x,t) \sim \exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{4(\sigma^2/\tau) t} \right]
$$

So, can we  evaluate the integral through some asymptotics, such that I get the corrections to the Gaussian form given for large $x$ and $t$?

Comment: What can be said about $x, t$ apart from $x, \,t/\tau\gg1$? Do you have some additional conditions, for example, $x^2/(t/\tau)\ll\,\,\gg1$?